# C# - Sorting Data to/from ListBoxes with Regex

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, listbox, text-files

I have a file with data in it that I would like to split up into three different ListBoxes.  I want the first ListBox to contain all of the data (a new list item for every line of data read from the text document).

**Main ListBox:**

```
D1
D2
C9
R7
R1
C130
D99
Q9
```

**Second ListBox:** (after a regex was used to match values that start with **D**)

```
D1
D2
D99
```

**Third ListBox:** (after a regex was used to match values that start with **C**)

```
C9
C130
```

And after those values were matched for the **SECOND** and **THIRD** ListBoxes, the

***New*** Main ListBox will look like this:

```
R7
R1
Q9
```

---

***CODE***

```
    static List<string> findPackagePlacementOneType(List<string> list)
    {
        // Creates a new list to return with new format.
        var result = new List<string>();

        // Checks each line in the list.
        foreach (var line in list)
        {
            // PLACEMENT ONE Regex
            Match regexRES = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(RES)");
            Match regex0402 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(0402)");
            Match regex0201 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(0201)");
            Match regex0603 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(0603)");
            Match regex0805 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(0805)");
            Match regex1206 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(1206)");
            Match regex1306 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(1306)");
            Match regex1608 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(1608)");
            Match regex3216 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(3216)");
            Match regex2551 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(2551)");
            Match regex1913 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(1913)");
            Match regex1313 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(1313)");
            Match regex2513 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(2513)");
            Match regex5125 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(5125)");
            Match regex2525 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(2525)");
            Match regex5619 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(5619)");
            Match regex3813 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(3813)");
            Match regex1508 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(1508)");
            Match regex6431 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(6431)");
            Match regex2512 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(2512)");
            Match regex1505 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(1505)");
            Match regex2208 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(2208)");
            Match regex1005 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(1005)");
            Match regex1010 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(1010)");
            Match regex2010 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(2010)");
            Match regex0505 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(0505)");
            Match regex0705 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(0705)");
            Match regex1020 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(1020)");
            Match regex1812 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(1812)");
            Match regex2225 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(2225)");
            Match regex5764 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(5764)");
            Match regex4532 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(4532)");
            Match regex1210 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(1210)");
            Match regex0816 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(0816)");
            Match regex0363 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(0363)");
            Match regexSOT = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(SOT)");

            if (regexRES.Success || regex0402.Success || regex0201.Success || regex0603.Success ||
                regex0805.Success || regex1206.Success || regex1306.Success || regex1608.Success ||
                regex3216.Success || regex2551.Success || regex1913.Success || regex1313.Success ||
                regex2513.Success || regex5125.Success || regex2525.Success || regex5619.Success ||
                regex3813.Success || regex1508.Success || regex6431.Success || regex2512.Success ||
                regex1505.Success || regex2208.Success || regex1005.Success || regex1010.Success ||
                regex2010.Success || regex0505.Success || regex0705.Success || regex1020.Success ||
                regex1812.Success || regex2225.Success || regex5764.Success || regex4532.Success ||
                regex1210.Success || regex0816.Success || regex0363.Success || regexSOT.Success)
            {
                result.Add(string.Join(" ", line));
            }

            else
                result.Remove(line);
        }

        // Returns the new list so it can be formatted further.
        return result;
    }

    // Finds the placement 2 package types.
    static List<string> findPackagePlacementTwoType(List<string> list)
    {
        // Creates a new list to return with new format.
        var result = new List<string>();

        // Checks each line in the list.
        foreach (var line in list)
        {
            // PLACEMENT TWO Regex
            Match regexBGA = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(BGA)");
            Match regexSOP8 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(SOP8)");
            Match regexQSOP = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(QSOP)");
            Match regexTQSOP = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(TQSOP)");
            Match regexSOIC16 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(SOIC16)");
            Match regexSOIC12Plus = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(SOIC12)");
            Match regexSOIC8 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(SOIC8)");
            Match regexSO8 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(SO8)");
            Match regexSO08 = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(SO08)");
            Match regexCQFP = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(CQFP)");
            Match regexLCC = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(LCC)");
            Match regexLGA = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(LGA)");
            Match regexOSCCC = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(OSCCC)");
            Match regexPLCC = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(PLCC)");
            Match regexQFN = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(QFN)");
            Match regexQFP = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(QFP)");
            Match regexSOJ = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(SOJ)");
            Match regexSON = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(SON)");

            if (regexBGA.Success || regexSOP8.Success || regexQSOP.Success || regexTQSOP.Success ||
               regexSOIC16.Success || regexSOIC12Plus.Success || regexSOIC8.Success || regexSO8.Success ||
               regexSO08.Success || regexCQFP.Success || regexLCC.Success || regexLGA.Success ||
               regexOSCCC.Success || regexPLCC.Success || regexQFN.Success || regexQFP.Success ||
               regexSOJ.Success || regexSON.Success)
            {
                result.Add(string.Join(" ", line));
            }

            else
                result.Remove(line);
        }

        // Returns the new list so it can be formatted further.
        return result;
    }

    static List<string> findPackagePlacementChoiceType(List<string> list)
    {
        // Creates a new list to return with new format.
        var result = new List<string>();

        // Checks each line in the list.
        foreach (var line in list)
        {
            // PLACEMENT CHOICE Regex
            Match regexCAP = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(CAP)");
            Match regexIND = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(IND)");
            Match regexMELF = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(MELF)");
            Match regexDIOM = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(DIOM)");
            Match regexSOD = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(SOD)");
            Match regexSTO = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(STO)");
            Match regexTO = Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(TO)");

            if (regexCAP.Success || regexIND.Success || regexMELF.Success || regexDIOM.Success ||
               regexSOD.Success || regexSTO.Success || regexTO.Success)
            {
                result.Add(string.Join(" ", line));
            }

            else
                result.Remove(line);
        }

        // Returns the new list so it can be formatted further.
        return result;
    }
```

---

***QUESTIONS***

I currently have my regular expressions that sort through and divide the file up into three seperate ListBoxes.. However... I would rather have the data placed in one of the ListBoxes and then sorted/removed from that ListBox if it matches the proper regular expression.

- How do I go about loading the .txt document into the ListBox (with every new line being a new item in the ListBox) and then going through each line in the **main ListBox** with regex to determine if the lines go into a different **second** or **third ListBox** or stay in the **main ListBox**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of multiple regexes you could just combine them into one.

You also don’t need to call `Regex.Match` followed by `match.Success`; just call `Regex.IsMatch`.

I don’t understand why you are using `result.Remove(line)`. You never added that non-matching line, so why do you need to remove it?

Finally, I don’t think you need to make the method specific to using `List<string>`. You can make it more general by specifying `IEnumerable<string>`.

I’ve rewritten the first one to demonstrate the principle:

```
static IEnumerable<string> findPackagePlacementOneType(IEnumerable<string> list)
{
    return list.Where(line => Regex.IsMatch(line,
        @"^.+(RES|0402|0201|0603|0805|1206|1306|1608|3216|2551|1913|1313|2513" +
        @"|5125|2525|5619|3813|1508|6431|2512|1505|2208|1005|1010|2010|0505" +
        @"|0705|1020|1812|2225|5764|4532|1210|0816|0363|SOT)"
    ));
}
```

If you ever really need a new `List<string>`, you can just add `.ToList()` after a call to `findPackagePlacementOneType`.

Comment: I tried to replace my function call to **findPackagePlacementOneType** with your similar function and for some reason it grabs everything instead of the regex that it should be grabbing..?

Comment: @Colton: Then you are doing something else wrong. I tested the function and it works as expected.

Comment: I got it working properly. I had placed it in the wrong spot. Thank you Timwi

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend making a few `ObservableCollection<string>`s, one for each of your `ListBox`es.  `ObservableCollection`s raise events when items are added or removed, which allows things like `ListBox`es to automatically update when they change.  Say they're called `items1`, `2`, and `3`.  Start with `items1 = new ObservableCollection<string>(list);`, and the other initialized as empty collections.  Also, rework the methods you posted to take a single `string` and return a `bool` saying whether it matched any.

Part 1, putting your collections of strings into the `ListBox`es:

```
mainListBox.ItemsSource = items1;
listBox2.ItemsSource = items2;
listBox3.ItemsSource = items3;
```

Part 2, going through each item in the list:

```
foreach (string str in items1.ToArray())
{
    if (isPackagePlacementOneType(str))
    {
        items1.Remove(str);
        items2.Add(str);
    } else if ...
}
```

The .ToArray() is the LINQ extension; it's needed because you can't modify an enumerable that you're iterating through.

Part 3: Also, I'd recommend reworking the methods a bit, based on the Do not Repeat Yourself (DRY) principle:

```
static readonly string[] match1 = new [] { "RES", ... };
static readonly string[] match2 = new [] { "BGA", ... };
static readonly string[] match3 = new [] { "CAP", ... };
//(then in the methods)
return match1.Any(x=>Regex.Match(line, @"^.+(" + x + ")").Success);
```

This also has the benefit of not needing to evaluate dozens of regex's that don't end up being read at all.